# Popover not popping up

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I want to show a popover when i click on a `href` which i am appending dynamically, but the popover is not popping up.

I tried to achieve the feat with the below codes.

```
<div id="myPopoverContent">
   ...stuff...
</div>

<div id="div3" style= "width:200px;height:200px;">
</div>
<div id = "div4"></div>
```

Below is the jQuery part:

```
$(document).on("click","#div3", function(index){
        var $div2 = $("<a id='div2' rel = 'popover' data-container='body' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='right' data-html='true'>bla</a>");
        $("#div4").append($div2);
        console.log("here2");

    });
//Popover part
    $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
        content: $('#myPopoverContent').html(),
        html: true
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).popover('show');
    });
```

However i tried to add popover setting manually as well as below but in vain.

```
var popOverSettings = {
    placement: 'bottom',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    selector: '[rel="popover"]', //Sepcify the selector here
    content: function () {
        return $('#popover-content').html();
    }
}

$('body').popover(popOverSettings);
```

Please note all the jQuery is under `document ready`.

All should lead to something like this:

```js
$('[data-toggle=popover]').popover({
    content: $('#myPopoverContent').html(),
    html: true
}).click(function() {
    $(this).popover('show');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="myPopoverContent">
   ...stuff...
</div>
<a ng-href = "" data-toggle="popover"><span class="badge">12</span> You have 12 messages.</a>
```

Comment: Your snippet seems to be working fine. What is the issue?

Comment: Snippet works....

Comment: I added the snippet to show you what i want to achieve. My intention is to achieve that with dynamically appended `<a>`.

Comment: i think you should use sytax below for creating anchor tag: 
var newtag = document.createElement( "a" );
And then you should set its attributes using sytax below:
jQuery(yourtag).attr(attname,attvalue);
And finally append it.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the popover after creating the jQuery object. For example:

```
$(document).on("click","#div3", function(index){
    var $div2 = $("<a id='div2' rel = 'popover' data-container='body' data-toggle='popover' data-placement='right' data-html='true'>bla</a>");
    $("#div4").append($div2);

    $div2.popover({
        content: $('#myPopoverContent').html(),
        html: true
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).popover('show');
    });

    console.log("here2");
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27713/